# Where to call next() if using foreach to iterate over Change in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx-8

To listen [`ObservableList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ObservableList.html) I am using the following code in listener:

```
@Override
public void onChanged(ListChangeListener.Change<? extends MyClass> c) {
    for(MyClass s : c.getAddedSubList()) {
        // process s
    }
}
```

unfortunately, I am getting a lot of exceptions:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid Change state: next() must be called before inspecting the Change.
```

Should I call `next()` before my loop? But this contradicts the statement from [`ListChangeListener` javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ListChangeListener.Change.html) saying `getList()` should work at any time, and that `getAddedSubList()` is just a shortcut of `getList()` expression.

Answer (score 6):

A change event may be fired for a single event that cannot be represented by a single set of results from `ListChangeListener.Change.getXXX()` methods. (For example, if you call `setAll(...)` on your observable list, under some circumstances.) To account for such changes you have to iterate through a collection of "change representations", getting the information for each of them. The proper idiom to use is

```
@Override
public void onChanged(ListChangeListener.Change<? extends MyClass> c) {
    while (c.next()) {
        if (c.wasAdded()) {
            for(MyClass s : c.getAddedSubList()) {
                // process s
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: wondering if you meant removeAll as an example of disjoint sub-changes: setAll fires a single replaced (if old/new content is not empty) or added/removed if either old/new content was/is empty. Or I might be missing something, and eager to learn what I overlooked :-)

Comment: Yes, `removeAll(...)` is a better example. I was thinking something like `FXCollections.observableList("A","B","C").setAll("1","B","2");` could propagate multiple sub-changes; and it could, but it doesn't (in the current implementation).

Comment: ahh thanks, ... see what you mean: not firing if a the new content contains an old element at the same location?

Answer (score 0):

> Important: It's necessary to call next() method before calling any
>   other method of Change. The same applies after calling reset(). The
>   only methods that works at any time is getList().

So yes, it has to be called, as:

> This is actually a shortcut to c.getList().subList(c.getFrom(),
>   c.getTo());

It also calls `c.getFrom()` and `c.getTo()`.